# SSRS Parameter Not Dynamically Updating - Last Day of Month

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2017

Report has two parameters

```
DateFrom
DateTo
```

DateTo set to "Always Refresh"

I have the following expression for `DateTo` - Default Values - so that it will dynamically default to the last of the month set by `DateFrom`

```
=DateSerial(Year(Parameters!DateFrom.Value), Month(Parameters!DateFrom.Value), "1").AddMonths(1).AddSeconds(-1)
```

However, the field doesn't update.
It shows the correct last date of month when `DateFrom` is selected the first time.

If `DateFrom` is set to 15/02/2019 then `DateTo` will show "28/02/2019 23:59:59".
But if you subsequently change `DateFrom` to a different month, `DateTo` doesn't update - still shows "28/02/2019 23:59:59".

Comment: After you select the `DateFrom` date, do you tab out of the date parameter? I don't think it will set the date selected until you tab out...

Comment: No change, still doesn't update

Answer (score 0):

I have just added these Parameter properties
1) data type -> date/time and allow nulls 
2) available values -> specify values -> label and value as

```
=DateSerial(Year(Parameters!Datefrom.Value), Month(Parameters!Datefrom.Value), "1").AddMonths(1).AddSeconds(-1)
```

3) Advanced=always refresh. and checked notify me box.
This works the moment i change param 1 ('Datefrom') i get new dateto as last date from month.

Are your settings matching this?

Comment: this works in "Available values" but prevents the user from being able to change the date if so required.